# Zeit's "micro" never resolves the promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, microservices

I'm scratching my head over little piece of code, that never resolves the `promise`. It doesn't even tell me that the `promise` is probably rejected.

```
const https = require('https'),
    {
        json
    } = require('micro')

module.exports = async () => {
    let response = https.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1')
    const jsonData = await json(response, {
        encoding: 'utf8'
    })
    console.log(jsonData)
}
```

Reading the [documentation](https://github.com/zeit/micro#body-parsing), the code is correct, it's just I don't understand why doesn't the promise log the response, instead the terminal is just blinking the cursor.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`json` is for handling a request body from an incoming request to your server (`http.IncomingMessage`). `https.get` returns a `ClientRequest`. You need to use the callback of `https` to get the response:

```
https.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1', async res => {
  const jsonData = await json(res, {
    encoding: 'utf8'
  });
  console.log(jsonData)
});
```

You may want to use a library like `axios` to integrate promises with `IncomingMessage`

```
const { data } = await axios({ url, responseType: 'stream' });
const jsonData = await json(data, { encoding: 'utf8' });
```

However note that axios and other such libraries have built in JSON parsing for responses as well.

Comment: It works this way, but if I wrap it up in `module.exports = async () => {...}` or `module.exports = () => {...}` it doesn't work. Do you know why does it behaves like that? Is there a documentation where I can learn more about it?

Comment: @VladimirJovanović can you show me your entire code that doesn't work?

Comment: I was messing with it and in the end I got it to getting working. I've declared the `https.get()` in a variable and then exported that variable afterwards.